# Space between character

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I am using the following code to print a `DateTimePicker` selected date in C# printing.

```
string theDate1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
g.DrawString("" + theDate1 + "  .", new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Brown, new PointF(510, 68));
```

And the result is like this : `15072015`

I need to keep spaces between these dates. If I writing this code to print only the date or month or year in every type need to keep spaces between character.
e.g : I need a result like  this : `1 5 0 7 2 0 1 5`
How can I do this

Comment: And do you think there will be a [printing] answer or that it will come down to string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is like this:

```
string theDate1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
theDate1 = string.Join(" ", theDate1.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to using directives at top of page:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then simply use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
theDate1 = theDate1.Aggregate(string.Empty, (d, i) => d + i + ' ');//1 5 0 7 2 0 1 5
```

Comment: I was about to post a solution using `.SelectMany`, but this is much nicer. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
StringBuilder SB= new     StringBuilder();

foreach (char ch in theDate1)
{
    SB.Append(ch);
    SB.Append(" ");
}
var result =SB.ToString().TrimEnd();
```

Comment: You are welcome. Pay attention that I use StringBuilder for concatenation and not string. If you are not familiar with it, I suggest you to read more about on the difference between them .

Comment: @ehh - what do you mean by "Pay attention that I use StringBuilder for concatenation and not string"?

Comment: I could define a string variable instead a StringBuilder and on each iteration doing concatenation of the string. But on each concatenation a new string instance is created, using StringBuilder is not the case

Comment: Actually your solution is incorrect, because it will append an extra space (`" "`) at the end of the string, so you'll get `1 5 0 7 2 0 1 5 ` instead of `1 5 0 7 2 0 1 5`, which is what OP's expecting to get. You should call `Trim()` or `TrimEnd()` after calling `ToString()`.

Comment: @ehh - in this case the OP is displaying a string that would effectively fit on a single line so it hardly needs the efficiency of a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - You are correct but it is a good practice to use StringBuilder instead of string. And if I can give some new knowledge to others, why not?

Comment: @Grx70 - Correct, 10x for the correction. I wouldn't say that it is incorrect but almost correct. The idea is understandable and for Mohamed Shakir, it was helpful.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theDate1.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write(theDate1[i].ToString() + " "); 
}
```